# What controls how much of a Spark Cluster is given to an application?

Tags: resources, apache-spark

In this page of the docs https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html for static partitioning it says "With this approach, each application is given a maximum amount of resources it can use".

I was just wondering, what are these maximum resources? I found the memory per executor setting (mentioned just below in dynamic partitioning) this I assume limits the memory resource an application gets. But what decides how many executors are started / how many nodes from the cluster are used e.g. the total cluster memory and the cores that get "taken"?

On another similar note is there a way to change the memory asked for on a per job or task level?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The amount of resources depends on the cluster manager being used as different cluster managers will provide different allocation.

Eg In standalone mode, Spark will try to use all nodes.  `spark.max.cores` will control how many cores in total the job will take across nodes. If not set, Spark will use `spark.deploy.defaultCores`. The documentation from [`spark.deploy.defaultCores`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/spark-standalone.html) further clarifies its use:

> Default number of cores to give to applications in Spark's standalone
>   mode if they don't set spark.cores.max. If not set, applications
>   always get all available cores unless they configure spark.cores.max
>   themselves. Set this lower on a shared cluster to prevent users from
>   grabbing the whole cluster by default.

In Mesos coarse grained mode, Spark will allocate by default all available cores. Use `spark.max.cores` to limit that per job.

In Mesos fine-grained mode, Spark will allocate a core per task as needed by the job and release them afterwards. This ensures fair usage at the cost of higher task allocation overhead.

In YARN, per [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html):

> The --num-executors option to the Spark YARN client controls how many
>   executors it will allocate on the cluster, while --executor-memory and
>   --executor-cores control the resources per executor.

Regarding memory, there's no way to set the total memory per job or task, only per executor, using `spark.executor.memory`. The memory assigned to your job will be `spark.executor.memory x #executors`.

Comment: Beautifully Written. just a follow-up question, is there a way to start more than one task per executor per Application ? this question came from my scenario where I have only one application running on my cluster and the ideal number of tasks per executor is 2 to 3, I presume